# Can't save file to disk, no clue why

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, nsmutablestring

I'm trying to write a string to disk:

```
return [fileContent writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:error];
```

But it always fails with the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The folder “ddd.csv” doesn’t exist." UserInfo=0xc4a08b0 {NSUnderlyingError=0xc49ba60 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSFilePath=file://<path to file>, NSUserStringVariant=Folder}
```

The path to the file seems to be valid (I've obscured it here) and the string (NSMutableString) is definitely not 0 length. This code used to work before Mountain Lion. Can anyone help shed a light on what could be going on?

**Edit:**
The value of `path` is: `file://localhost/Users/cocoaster/Downloads/ddd.csv`

Comment: Would help to know what the value of `path` is. And most likely your app is sandboxed so accessing anything outside of that will give you an error.

Comment: Yep, 99% certain that you simply are not providing the right directory.  Files need to go into one of the subdirectories of the app's private direcory

Comment: I've added the value of path. I'm running this under Xcode but I don't remember setting up anything in terms of sandboxing.

Comment: That's a URL or URL string not a typical file path.  Try /Users/cocoaster/Downloads/ddd.csv

Comment: This is supposed to be a path selected by the end user. How can I let my users save to disk?

Comment: BTW, is this a "native" OSx app or an iOS/iPhone app?

Comment: Selected how? Is this from a save panel?

Comment: Save panel returns aURL not a path. You need to convert to a path [url path]

Comment: Or, use writeToURL:atomically: instead.

Comment: Perfect. Can you put that into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using a save panel the result comes back as a URL, so if you need a path, convert the result to a path with the path command:  [url path].

Alternately, you can use writeToURL:atomically: if that version is available for whatever class fileContent is.

Comment: URLs are recommended over paths in modern code, and NSStrings do respond to `writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:`.